# Laravel cannot find file in directory?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4

http://angulairapi.rohanchhabra.in/airports

This is a very simple route I have created in Laravel. It just takes a json file in the public directory, decodes it into an array and return the same json in response.

If you go the route (mentioned above), the error say "No such file or directory" but it exists in fact. It is working fine on my local machine. But when I pushed the same thing on my server, it is giving me this error.

http://gitlab.learningtechasia.com:8901/rohan0793/angulairapi.git

I have made the repository public so that everyone can have a look.

Comment: Does the .htaccess file exist in your public directory (on the server)?

Comment: I'll have to look, but it must, because I just did a git clone of the repository.

Comment: Ok. If you're on it also check if .htaccess is enabled

Comment: .htaccess is enabled?

Comment: Yes .htaccess needs to be enabled [This should help](http://askubuntu.com/questions/429869/is-this-a-correct-way-to-enable-htaccess-in-apache-2-4-7-on-ubuntu-12-04) You can also check if `/index.php/airports` works. If yes, something with your .htaccess doesn't work

Comment: I have other projects on the same machine with different sub domains already running. I think it should be enabled.

Comment: Ouh... I finally clicked on your link. No that definitely has nothing to do with .htaccess. Seems like Anand Patel's answer could be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested on my machine asset() is working for me and the path(public/airports.json) you have written reflect same error for me.

Laravel`s Helper function asset("file_name") generate a URL for an asset.

please check laravel`s [helper](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers) function documentation for more detail

put this code in your routes.php and try again

```
<?php

Route::get('/airports', function(){
    $airports = json_decode(file_get_contents(asset("airports.json")));
    return Response::json($airports);
});

Route::get('/flights', function(){
    $airports = json_decode(file_get_contents(asset("flights.json")));
    return Response::json($airports);
});
```

**EDIT**

When you are working on local machine your url having word public i.e localhost/project-name/public/airports.json.

but when you deploy project on server it seems it remove public word from url, so what happing here, server finding airports.json at location http://angulairapi.rohanchhabra.in/public/airports.json  but its not actually there its at location http://angulairapi.rohanchhabra.in/airports.json, so it is recommended to use laravel function(in this case asset()) to generate url/assets link.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Works like a charm now! Thank you.

Comment: It is working fine on my server but stopped working on my local machine for some reason. Any idea?

Comment: Nothing. It just wouldn't load anymore. It keeps on waiting for localhost

Comment: hmm for me its working same on localhost, are you using windows ?

Comment: Tried it both on windows and Ubuntu! :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67410/discussion-between-anand-patel-and-rohan).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `asset()` and Anands answer is the helper function [`public_path()`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#paths). It returns an absolute file path from the system point of view and not a URL.

```
$airports = json_decode(file_get_contents(public_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."airports.json")));
```

`asset()` should be used for URLs to files. URLs that you send to the client. You should work with `public_path()` for internal things, such as getting the content of a file.